# Using list environment to refactor messy table

Tags: tables, paragraphs

I'm writing a book using Latex (obviously). Xetex actually. I'm
doing a lot of tables w/ `\parbox`es in the table cells. In the end
there's alot of repetitions and the code looks bad as a result (it's
hard to find the content for the trees~). I faintly believe I've seen
some suggestions in the direction of using some sort of list
environment as well as custom (modular?) commands and lengths to
refactor the code and do this leaner. Is that possible? How would that
go?

I'd be so greatfull for the help.

My MWE, out of the book, goes like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for the Swedish chars
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
    \toprule
    Lager & Vävnad & Syfte\\
    \midrule
    \parbox[t][][t]{.15\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Tunica intima
    } &
    \parbox[t][][t]{.25\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Tunt lager av endotelceller på insidan av ett lager av
      epitel- och bindvävsceller. 
    } &
    \parbox[t][][t]{.4\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Endotelet har flera viktiga funktioner.
    } \\

    \parbox[t][][t]{.15\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Tunica medica 
    } &
    \parbox[t][][t]{.25\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Smidig muskelvävnad och bindväv.
    } &
    \parbox[t][][t]{.4\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Genom att kontrahera musklerna minskar lumen och blodtrycket
      höjs.
    } \\

    \parbox[t][][t]{.15\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Tunica externa 
    } &
    \parbox[t][][t]{.25\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Yttre, skyddande bindvävslager.
    } &
    \parbox[t][][t]{.4\textwidth}{\raggedright\em
      Skyddar och håller kärlet i läge.
    } \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}  
  \caption[Kärlväggarnas tre lager]{De tre lagren som kärlväggarna
    består av.\label{tab:tunica}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX provides a `p{length}` specifier for this purpose.  With `array.sty`, you can reduce the amount of repeated code by defining a new column specifier:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for the Swedish chars
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight\itshape}p{#1\textwidth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}N{.15}N{.25}N{.4}@{}}
    \toprule
    Lager & Vävnad & Syfte\\
    \midrule
    Tunica intima
          & Tunt lager av endotelceller på insidan av ett lager av
            epitel- och bindvävsceller. 
                   & Endotelet har flera viktiga funktioner. \\
    Tunica medica
          & Smidig muskelvävnad och bindväv.
                   & Genom att kontrahera musklerna minskar lumen och blodtrycket
                     höjs. \\
    Tunica externa 
          & Yttre, skyddande bindvävslager.
                   & Skyddar och håller kärlet i läge.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}  
  \caption[Kärlväggarnas tre lager]{De tre lagren som kärlväggarna
    består av.\label{tab:tunica}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Both great answers. Thanks. They're qualitative quite similar (I
think) and since Arash is the least in reputation and first to answer,
I hope I do the right thing by giving the green checkmark for the
first answer.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution with `tabularx`. I also added (automatically) some vertical padding between rows, with the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for the Swedish chars
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for the Swedish chars
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\itshape\arraybackslash\hsize=.18\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\RaggedRight\itshape\arraybackslash\hsize=.32\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\itshape\arraybackslash\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{L, M, R}

 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[tb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}S{L}S{M}S{R}@{}}
    \toprule
    Lager & Vävnad & Syfte\\
    \midrule
    Tunica intima
          & Tunt lager av endotelceller på insidan av ett lager av
            epitel- och bindvävsceller.
                   & Endotelet har flera viktiga funktioner. \\
    Tunica medica
          & Smidig muskelvävnad och bindväv.
                   & Genom att kontrahera musklerna minskar lumen och blodtrycket
                     höjs. \\
    Tunica externa
          & Yttre, skyddande bindvävslager.
                   & Skyddar och håller kärlet i läge.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[Kärlväggarnas tre lager]{De tre lagren som kärlväggarna
    består av.\label{tab:tunica}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both great answers. Thanks. They're qualitative quite similar (I
think) and since Arash is the least in reputation and first to answer,
I hope I do the right thing by giving the green checkmark for the
first answer.

Comment: ...even though I, now, realize this might be a refinement of the previous answer. I was simply stuck figuring out which was the "best" answer. Anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mats: That's fine with me. I  don't post answers to  win checkmarks, but to be helpful. The first answer is a very good answer – I just thought it could still be improved (to my taste…) using some other tools.

Comment: Great, but it's tricky choosing the right one. You giys ARE so hlpfull abd that drive you share to be that is something to be careful of. Thanks for your improved suggestion. Be well. Cheers.